# Wirelessly debug Safari web app running on iOS using Safari on macOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac-mini

I need to plug an iPad/iPhone into a Mac Mini so I can debug web pages running ApplePay on them using the macOS Safari developer console.

**Complication**: The Mac mini is in a server cupboard three rooms away (considerably further away than the hard USB 5 metre limit). It runs headless and I VNC into it via my desktop PC.

So, how to connect the Apple devices without physically moving them? Is there some sort of wireless USB bridging device out there?

Currently installed software versions:

- iOS: iOS 11.4.1
- macOS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Desktop Safari: Safari 11.1.2

Comment: Please edit the question and mention the version of iOS running on your devices along with the version of macOS and Safari running on Mac mini.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Follow the instructions below one by one:

1. On your iOS device, go to Settings app → Safari → Advanced and enable the switch for **Web Inspector**.

[image]

2. On macOS, launch Safari and in the Menu bar, go to Preferences → Advanced and check **Show Develop menu in menu bar**.

[image]

3. You will need to physically connect your iOS device to Mac mini using the Lightning cable once.
4. Once the iOS device is connected, in Safari menu on macOS, enable Develop → *Your device name* → Connect via Network.
5. Unplug the cable and check whether Develop → *Your device name* shows up in Safari on macOS.
6. Safari app needs to be running and frontmost on your iOS device for it to appear under Develop menu in Safari on macOS.

The above configuration is demonstrated on devices running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and iOS 11.4.1 (latest version at the time of writing).

Comment: Brilliant - never knew this was possible. Works for the development iPhone but alas not for the iPad. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to connect the cable just for the first time, or every time you start using this feature?

Comment: @RoboRobok I thought this to but this is not the case. First the cable is required, but after that you have connected you can go to Safari > Development > iPhone and check Connect through Network. After that you can unplug the USB-cable.

Comment: it works but it crash all the time - maybe for huge data 2MB+ on the page

Comment: @BGBruno Check if you are running the latest version of iOS/iPadOS and macOS software.

Comment: thx - I have it checked - and I still have to connect cable - make no sense - omg lol :-)

Comment: @Mark Thank you for pointing out that on the mac computer, we must go back to the Develop menu and click "Connect through Network" and then we can unplug the lightning cable. I love this 

Comment: @BGBRUNO I also experience frequent crashes, and the best solution I found is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538957/480608. Sometimes killing all the other apps on the device fixes it. Apparently it is related to memory consumption.

Comment: @RaineRevere highly possible memory - or I figure out with cable it can be " broken data part in cable " 

Answer (score 1):

Further to Nimesh Neema's answer, which I summarise as:

- iOS device (remote) → Settings app → Safari → Advanced and enable Web Inspector, plug in device to Mac via cable to pair it (first time only).
- MacOS device (local) → Preferences → Advanced → Show Develop menu in menu bar, then Develop → Your device name → Connect via Network.

Here's tips for troubleshooting this:

- If it stops working, try plugging in the cable again as a temporary measure. Be patient.
- If the iOS device loses network connection and refuses to reconnect, give the network up to five minutes to settle down.
- Test that your Mac can see (ping) the iOS device on the network.
- Ideally assign a static IP address or reserve a single IP address on your wireless router so it's the same each time -- this can improve speed and reliability considerably.
- If you have multiple wifi networks, ideally ensure both devices are on the same SSID/network.
- If this still doesn't fix this issue, try unpairing the two, turn all the relevant options off on iOS and MacOS, relaunch Safari, turn all the options on again. Worst case, try restarting the Mac. Beyond that there are a few more low-level ways to force a pairing refresh, which I've only ever had to use once.

These are what I find generally help - I use network debugging method a lot.

Comment: Wow, that seems _quite buggy_ for a debugging feature. And I thought Android wireless debugging was complicated.